# Importing data from Stooq with Pandas datareader returns empty dataframe in Python, but works in Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-datareader

Importing stock-indexes like ^DJI from Stooq With Pandas Datareader in Jupyter Notebook Works great, but when I try the exact same script in Python 3.7 it Returns Empty dataframe. Why is that? and how can I solve it?

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

df = pdr.DataReader("^DJI", "stooq")

print (df)
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem is in how `Stooq` symbols are enriched in `StooqDailyReader`. The function `"_get_params"` is going to add to each symbol a country name e.g. "US". The symbol "^DJI" will therefore be "^DJI.US" and the download URL generated will not work or result in an empty file.

I have quick fixed this by commenting out the following function block:

```
    symbol_parts = symbol.split(".")
    if len(symbol_parts) == 1:
        symbol = ".".join([symbol, country])
    else:
        if symbol_parts[1].lower() not in ['de', 'hk', 'hu', 'jp',
                                           'pl', 'uk', 'us']:
            symbol = ".".join([symbol, ''])
```

Hope this fix also you issue.